# How to avoid plugin name conflicts from the upgrade notifier?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, upgrade

I've wrapped a quick hack as a plugin to add Google Analytics to my site. Named it "Google Analytics" and, sure enough, WP offered me to upgrade my v0.1 plugin to some random plugin from the plugin repo.

I vaguely recall it getting raised a few times around WP 2.7 to 3.0. Is there a new API available somewhere to disable this, or is the only way to avoid it still is to prefix plugin names (not their file name, but their actual name as shown in the Plugins screen) to make them unique?

In my specific use case, the plugin is in `mc-ga/mc-ga.php` and is named "Google Analytics", along with a few other meta fields at the beginning of the plugin file header. WP yields an update notice based on "Google Analytics" (I couldn't locate a `mc-ga.php` plugin file in the repo).

Does WP allow to add an extra field I'm not aware of, e.g. a repo URL or something truly unique, so as to avoid such conflicts?

Comment: Couldn't you disable the update process for just that plugin you have created?  [This Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897044/wordpress-how-to-disable-plugin-update) shows how to go about it.

Comment: @josh: naturally, but I was hoping there was some kind of flag I wasn't aware of nowadays. My WP-fu is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove you plugin from the *updateble* list with:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function(){
    add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', function ( $value ) 
    {
        if( isset( $value->response['google-analytics/google-analytics.php'] ) )
            unset( $value->response['google-analytics/google-analytics.php'] );
        return $value;
    });
});
```

Adding this filter will eliminate our homonymous plugin altogether from update checks. And it supposes that we are doing the updates manually via simple FPT uploads -or similar. But there are many factors, as discussed in [If I rename a plugin (in its main php file) do I still get update notifications?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56968). As per the OP description (same name, different slug), without using a filter, maybe the best is to set the plugin `Version` header to a greater number or using a less conventional number like `yyyy.mm.dd`.

If we are setting [our own Repo](https://github.com/brasofilo/github-plugin-update-checker), I believe there won't be any conflicts.

Comment: Just to confirm: they've yet to add some kind of flag or repo information or something that I could toss in the plugin's description to avoid the problem altogether?

Comment: I don't get your doubt... IIRC, what Otto said is that there are a number of factors that weight when checking for updates, not only the name (but Description is not one of them). . . . I'll update the A.

Comment: My doubt is so: In my specific use case, the plugin is in mc-ga/mc-ga.php and is named "Google Analytics", along with a few other meta fields at the beginning of the plugin file header. WP yields an update notice based on "Google Analytics" (I couldn't locate a mc-ga.php plugin file in the repo). My WP-fu is a bit rusty, but I was kind of hoping that, by now, WP would allow to add an extra field I'm not aware of, e.g. a repo url or something truly unique, so as to avoid such conflicts.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. As your example demonstrates, simply a different slug is not enough. What if you set your version to `9999` or `yyyy.mm.dd` which is more logical and not so used? Oh, would be nice if you added this explanation to the Q.

Comment: Done. I'm not very found of the idea of losing the version. That said, the Codex page on plugin file headers links to ticket #12260 suggesting some of the readme data is being sent, but no luck locating anything related to that in the wp source code.

Comment: Adding this trac ticket on plugin GUIDs for reference, too: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10814

Comment: There's also http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8964 that introduced the ability to add extra headers. Will need to test that one a bit, to see what comes out.

Comment: Quite promising tickets to fine tune this process, I've added them to [WPSE#56968](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56968/if-i-rename-a-plugin-in-its-main-php-file-do-i-still-get-update-notifications).

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is: before making your plugin, first check whether the name you are going to give already exists in [WordPress plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/plugins/). If not, then you can move forward and develop the plugin.

Case it exists, give a different name to your plugin. Because the upgrade is based on the name, you can't manage two different plugins with same name. WordPress does this upgrade option automatically from the official repository.

Comment: Thanks for the code that may help in future.+1 @brasofilo

Comment: Yep, it's a simple step, but effective. The matter is when it's a plugin to use in our own sites, we *want* that specific name for us. So, please, WP, bug me not, this one is mine ;)

Comment: I don't think that's an adequate solution, because there's no way to guarantee that there won't be a conflicting plugin in the future. In fact, an attacker could intentionally create a matching plugin in order to install arbitrary code on your server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a plugin that's custom for a site, then give its name the site's name as a prefix.

We're certainly not going to allow a plugin named "Example.com - Google Analytics" into the WordPress.org directory.

Additionally, add a "Plugin URI" field to the plugin header. The Plugin URI is used as part of the matching process, and provides something more unique than the name to match against as well.

Comment: You're in charge of maintaining that script, or at least partially authored it, correct? If so, there might be a bug in it, because the Plugin URI is most definitely filled in: http://pastebin.com/NXTHWxQs - WP confuses it with https://wordpress.org/plugins/googleanalytics/

Comment: No bug, you simply are trying to share a name with another plugin that also has a similar name. Choose a more unique name. Prefix it with the site name, that's what I do. The URI is used as a primary, but any match is considered better than no match. If you want it to not match, then it needs to *not match* on any level.

Comment: That *is* a bug from my view point. How about adding some kind of "Private: True" plugin header, or at least making sure that the slug and/or authors match before assuming A is in fact B? I mean, heck, I've been hacking into the WP API ever since it's been around, and the only thing I've ever needed to hack into it for was to disable false positives — of which there are way, way, way too many when you're dealing with custom-designed plugins.

Comment: You're welcome to your viewpoint, however I do not share it. If you are writing plugins and not putting them in the official repository, then you'll probably want to include code to disable the update checks for your plugin, or just name your plugins uniquely. Most plugin authors doing this have no problem with naming, as they want to add "branding" anyway. There are no plans to make a way for plugins to easily not check for updates. Quite the opposite, in fact.

Comment: So, in other words, you're saying that: if we don't know of a plugin in the wp.org repo, and some other plugin by some random coder with a random other slug has the same name (which is increasingly likely) and a higher version, we just toss in an update notice to make end-users upgrade to some random thing they never asked for and lose functionality in the process. Bravo. \*Clap! Clap!\* Great service for end-users.

Comment: How hard is it to simply change the name to something unique? Is it really that difficult? Do you have some problem with putting a sitename in the name field as a prefix? I legitimately do not understand your problem here. If you named your plugin "Akismet" or "Jetpack" then you wouldn't be having this argument here, would you? But because you can't be bothered to use a unique name, that's somehow our fault?

Comment: Allow me to throw that question straight back at you: how hard is it to simply monitor for slug/author/URI in the wp.org API? Is it a problem to destroy random end-user sites on the basis of making wp.org more visible? I would most definitely have this argument here if I were naming my plugin Akismet or Jetpack: if I fork either, I'd change their URI. From that point forward, they shouldn't get upgraded by wp.org. I monitor them and merge fixes if applicable — not my customers. Likewise, when I author a plugin called Google Analytics — of which there isn't just one but many in the plugin repo.

Comment: And by the way, that's not saying your answer is incorrect. It isn't at the end of the day, and I haven't down-voted it irrespective of how unhelpful it was. I'm merely stressing, based on my vague recollection that the API has your finger prints all over on it, that there's a world outside of wp.org and wp.com. That world is very, very poorly served. (http://www.wptavern.com/how-to-install-wordpress-plugins-directly-from-github by your colleague Sarah brings a ray of hope that things might change in the future, but I'm not holding my breath.)

Comment: For the record, that particular matching function in the API was not written by me, and it is mostly unchanged from when I first saw it about 4 years ago. I didn't write it, and if I did, it would probably be different. But I'm not about to change 6-7 year functionality which 50+ million sites rely on because somebody cannot be bothered to pick a unique name for their plugin. This isn't "new". It's very old. And backward compatibility is more important to me than what you think is "right".

Comment: In short, I would rather your plugin with a poorly chosen name get completely screwed for now, instead of potentially having several dozen or hundred plugins which don't have unique enough things in them suddenly stop getting possible security fixes for the future.

Comment: You're really convinced that those 50M sites rely on wp.org sending them erroneous update notifications, do you? ;-) I raised the issue back when it got initially developed if memory serves, fwiw. I also chuckled upon seeing an Automattician requesting plugin GUIDs (look it up) that have yet to get implemented shortly after it did — Westi eventually closed it as maybelater. And life goes up, with bugs unfixed. \*Sigh\*. Anyway, over and out I guess, since this discussion is evidently leading to nowhere. But if you've a say on this somehow, please raise it as a courtesy — I'll be very grateful.

Comment: I think GUIDs are a great idea, actually. Wish we would add them to core, so I could rewrite that part of the API to be much stronger. But until we have such a thing, I'm absolutely convinced that eliminating that which you consider to be "erroneous" would actually be a problem for a lot of current plugins/themes that rely on that behavior, yes.

Comment: The ticket being referred to is https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10814, if anyone is interested.

Comment: Also, https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32101

Answer (score 0):

Adding this one for posterity, in case anyone else needs it:

```
if (!defined('STRICTER_PLUGIN_UPDATES')) define('STRICTER_PLUGIN_UPDATES', false);

# ============
# WP Updates
# ============

if (STRICTER_PLUGIN_UPDATES) :

# - Drop plugin upgrades when the slugs don't match

add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', function($updates) {
    if (!$updates->response) return $updates;

    foreach ($updates->response as $key => $response) {
        $slug = strpos($key, '/') !== false ? dirname($key) : basename($key, '.php');
        if ($slug != $response->slug) {
            unset($updates->response[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $updates;
});

endif; # STRICTER_PLUGIN_UPDATES
```